# How to queue ajax request in offline mode and execute automatically when connects to internet using offline .js ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get, offline

Please explain with one ajax example. 
This is my current code

```
<div id="status">Status is:</div>
  <button onclick="getData()">Get Data</button>
  <script>
      // Set our options for the Offline detection library
      Offline.options = {
          checkOnLoad: true,
          checks: {
              image: {
                  url: function() {
                      return 'http://esri.github.io/offline-editor-js/tiny-image.png?
                  }
              },
              active: 'image'
          },
          requests : true
      }

      Offline.on('up', internetUp);
      Offline.on('down',internetDown);
      var statusDiv = document.getElementById("status");
      statusDiv.innerHTML = "Status is: " + Offline.state;

      function getData() {

          // See if internet is up or down
          Offline.check();
                  // If the internet is up go ahead and retrieve data.
                  $.ajax({url:"http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting", success: function(result){
                    debugger
alert(JSON.stringify(result));
    }});

      }

      function internetUp(){
          console.log("Internet is up.");
          statusDiv.innerHTML = "Status is: up";
      }

      function internetDown(){
          console.log("Internet is down.");
          statusDiv.innerHTML = "Status is: down";
      }
  </script>
```

I want to queue the ajax request calling in offline mode during calling and want to execute automaticaly when i connect to internet

Comment: It is fairly straight forward. instead of sending request, put the request parameters into the array. Once you are online - get items one by one from the beginning of the array and construct requests out of those. Often, however, results for late requests are no longer needed. So, it might be a more sound solution to send new requests, once you are online and not to bother with the queue, where the knowledge of the request's purpose is not present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Offline.on('up', internetUp);` is an event that fire `internetUp` function when internet is up. Then you could do something like:

```
    function internetUp(){
              console.log("Internet is up.");
              statusDiv.innerHTML = "Status is: up";

              var requests = ['example.com','example2.com','whatever.com'];


              for(let i =0;i<requests.length;i++){

                            $.ajax({
                    url: requests[i]
                  }).done(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);//here callback of each request
                  });          
              }
}
```

Where requests represents the queue ajax actions you want stored as array.